# Change in controller not reflected in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have 2 controllers based on the action taken in one controller, I need to update the data in the other. 
This is my code

Controller 1

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('PackageIns', $scope.pkgtoLoad);
```

Controller 2

```
    $rootScope.$on('PackageIns', function (event, args) {
       vm.order.Lines = args;
       console.log(vm.order.Lines)
    })
```

`vm.order.Lines` is an array of objects.The problem is The array `vm.order.Lines` is getting updated, but the view is not reflecting that. 
But if I put the code like this `vm.order.Lines= [];`, then the view will be reflected and view will be clearing all the lines.

**Edit**

View

```
<tbody tp-order-line ng-repeat="orderLine in vm.order.Lines track by vm.itemTracker(Line)" lineitem="Line">
```

Im using directive for rendering. 
The template used inside directive is

```
<td>{{vm.orderLine.Name}}</td>
<td>{{vm.orderLine.Description}}</td>
```

Comment: Can you check what is the type of args?

Comment: Args is also array of objects.

Comment: Could you please show the code of the view?

Comment: In the view outside the ng-repeat, can you add {{vm.order.Lines}} and see what gets displayed?

Comment: @ArunGhosh outside the directive the change is getting reflected for {{vm.order.Lines}}. But in the template there is no effect

Answer (score 0):

The fix I found was adding a timeout.This worked for me

```
 vm.order.Lines = [];
     $timeout(function () {
     vm.order.Lines = args;
    }, 100);
```